# I have implemented till Statements and State in Tree Walk Interpreter. I am pissed with an error

Tags: java, compiler-construction, crafting-interpreters

I have implemented till Statements and State in Tree Walk Interpreter. I am pissed with an error. Can you please help me fix this :

> print 5 + 4; [line ] Error at 'print': Expect expression. Exception in thread "main" com.piscan.Zealot.Parser$ParseError at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.error(Parser.java:131) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.primary(Parser.java:227) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.unary(Parser.java:202) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.factor(Parser.java:185) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.term(Parser.java:173) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.comparison(Parser.java:160) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.equality(Parser.java:50) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.expression(Parser.java:45) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.expressionStatement(Parser.java:78) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.statement(Parser.java:66) at com.piscan.Zealot.Parser.parse(Parser.java:37) at com.piscan.Zealot.Zealot.run(Zealot.java:85) at com.piscan.Zealot.Zealot.runPrompt(Zealot.java:66) at com.piscan.Zealot.Zealot.main(Zealot.java:25)

here's the code [Github](https://github.com/kmr-ankitt/Zealot)

This program is meant to evaluate

> print 5 + 5;
> as 10

but it is showing above mentioned error.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: please include a [mre] in the question - external links are not sufficient (they change, maybe blocked, or are just deleted; invalidating the question)

Comment: A project on github should have a build file.  And you shouldn't check in ".class" files.  (Do you really expect someone to run them?  Sure ... I'm happy to run random Java classes that could potentially do nasty things to my machine.  NOT!)

Comment: @StephenC luckily, there are services like [`gitpod.io`](https://www.gitpod.io/) 